# GTM trigger on event

Tags: google-analytics

We have an iframe on site we cannot control. From this, we are able to send an event to our GA account when an action is completed that we want to track, which we turned into a goal in GA.

We can't control the iframe so can do no more than have this event fire (they set it up). We cannot install GA or GTM on the iFrame.

Is there any way to setup a trigger within GTM to fire when that event is recorded in GA?

Thanks

David

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is trying to use the Analytics Real Time Reporting API.

Comment: You can trigger GTM in iframe just have to do some coding tricks, Just find and replace GTM ID with your GTM ID in iframe and it'll work smoothly, I have done same for one of my project and everything is getting track smoothly

Answer (score 0):

Instead of asking the iframe for an event, you can ask them to send you a window.postMessage(), which then you can listen to and dispatch a dataLayer event on, which then will trigger a tag in GTM and let you do all you want without having to hack into the third party iframe.